# PHP $filename - expects parameter 1 to be a resource error

Tags: php, json

I am trying to write this file to a json file on my server and have successfully done this in many other places but for some reason this one is throwing an error that I don't understand because the $filename is correct. This works for other feeds but not this one - it is roughly 3.5mb in size so not huge. Any ideas as to why it would throw this error when public_html/data/GeoMAC-Current-Fires.json is correct? This may seem like I duplicate but I did read every suggested question/answer to no avail.

> [14-Aug-2018 16:44:21 UTC] PHP Warning:  fopen(public_html/data/GeoMAC-Current-Fires.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home4/theprfk5/public_html/cronjobs/GeoMAC-Current-Fires.php on line 5
>   [14-Aug-2018 16:44:21 UTC] PHP Warning:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home4/theprfk5/public_html/cronjobs/GeoMAC-Current-Fires.php on line 6
>   [14-Aug-2018 16:44:24 UTC] PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /***/***/public_html/cronjobs/GeoMAC-Current-Fires.php on line 8

Code:

```
<?php
    $site = 'https://wildfire.cr.usgs.gov/arcgis/rest/services/geomac_dyn/MapServer/3/query?where=Active%20=%20%27Y%27&geometryprecision=4&outfields=incidentname,datecurrent,active,gisacres&f=geojson';
    $homepage = file_get_contents($site);
    $filename = 'public_html/data/GeoMAC-Current-Fires.json';
    $handle = fopen($filename,"w");
    fwrite($handle,$homepage);
    echo file_get_contents($site);
    fclose($handle);
?>
```

Comment: The file didn't open for some reason. You'll have to troubleshoot to find out why. The filename is on a relative path, so if the file you're executing is not in the directory above public_html, it's going to be incorrect. I'd suggest using an absolute path, or use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to specify where it should start looking.

Comment: `$filename = 'public_html` should have a leading slash for it `$filename = '/public_html` or a full server path `$filename = '/var/usr/public_html` or a relative path `'(../)data/...`  - the `(../)` is depending on where it is.

Comment: That is because it didn't find the file, try using the real path to that file ( http://yourweb.com/data/GeoMAC-Current-Fires.json)

Comment: That gave me a new error: failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in /home4/***/public_html/cronjobs/GeoMAC-Current-Fires.php on line 5

Comment: It looks like ../ worked but not /public_html/ or domainname/etc. Funny how the above works for other ones but not this one.

Answer (score 0):

These two lines cause the issue:

```
$filename = 'public_html/data/GeoMAC-Current-Fires.json';
$handle = fopen($filename,"w");
```

When `fopen()` tries to open `$filename` it returns false. Therefore `fwrite()` is trying to write to `false` which causes `fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ...`

You will need to make sure that your path in your `$filename` is correct. As – Héctor mentioned above, you will need use the real path to that file.